# mapbox : filter features based on 'tags' property (which is an array)

Tags: filter, mapbox

I have some features that have a `tags` property, which is an array:

```
[
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id":1,
        "tags": ["tagA","tagB"]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id":2,
        "tags": ["tagB","tagE"]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id":3,
        "tags": ["tagZ","tagF"]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id":4,
        "tags": ["tagN","tagP"]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id":5,
        "tags": ["tagY","tagT"]
    }
  }
]
```

Using a list of allowed tags,

```
 const allowedTags = ['tagY','tagZ']
```

**...what would be the syntax of a [Mapbox layer filter](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/) that would get the features having at least one tag from my input (in this example, the feature #3 and #5) ?**

I tested this

```
const tagsFilter = ['in', ['get', 'tags'], ['literal', ['tagY','tagZ']]];
map.setFilter("markers",tagsFilter);
```

But it does not work.  Seems this exact syntax should rather be used to compare a single value, like

```
const idFilter = ['in', ['get', 'id'], ['literal', [3,5]]];
```

Thanks !

Comment: Your example is wrong, 3 and 5 don't have both tagY and tagZ.

Comment: Thers's still no feature with tags both tagY and tagZ. Not sure what you're looking for here. Or do you want to filter them if they only have allowed tags, no need for all allowed tags to be there?

Comment: Not both. But at least one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out thanks to [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/rsh412/hue2783p/1/):

This would work

```
['any',
  ['in', 'tagY', ['get', 'tags']],
  ['in', 'tagZ', ['get', 'tags']]
]
```

I made a function out of it :

```
function getTagsFilter(tags){

  //no tags set
  if ( (tags || []).length === 0) return;

  //expression for each tag
  const tagFilters = tags.map(tag=>['in',tag,['get', 'tags']])

  return ['any'].concat(tagFilters);

}

const allowedTags = ['tagY','tagZ'];
map.setFilter("markers",getTagsFilter(allowedTags));//yeepee!
```

**Bonus**

to rather exclude those tags, just use

```
map.setFilter("markers",['!',getTagsFilter(disabledTags)]);//yeepee again!
```